# Snowflake table replace nulls with multiple values

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, upsert

I have database table at Snowflake, with NULL values.

| id | month |
| --- | --- |
| a01 | 5 |
| a02 | 6 |
| b01 | 6 |
| b04 | NULL |

I need transform it as this example:

| id | month |
| --- | --- |
| a01 | 5 |
| a02 | 6 |
| b01 | 6 |
| b04 | 7 |
| b04 | 8 |

I must replace `NULL`s with multiple values (with 2 values: `7` and `8` - summer months). So from each `NULL` row I need to make two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be with two separate statements, one to insert an extra row and one to update the existing `NULL` value:

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, month) 
SELECT id, 8 as month
FROM tab
WHERE month is NULL;
```

followed by

```
UPDATE tab 
SET month = 7
WHERE month is NULL;
```

Result:

| id | month |
| --- | --- |
| a01 | 5 |
| a02 | 6 |
| b01 | 6 |
| b04 | 7 |
| b04 | 8 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=4c1f116db824814ad2c29e978931bb18).